# How to extract text inside a li tag using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the HTML code from where I need to extract the text:

```
<li class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words">
Nilesh Sengupta
</li>
```

This is my code:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
print(items.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

`driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")` returns a list of web elements
So in order to extract texts from all the elements you have to iterate on all the elements in the list and extract text from each one.
So you should

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for el in items:
  print(el.text)
```

In case you want to extract a text from a specific element you should use `find_element_by_tag_name` instead of `find_elements_by_tag_name`.
In this case
`item = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("li")`
`item` is a web element and you can extract a text from it directly by
`print(item.text)`

Answer (score 1):

With `css` selectors is the best way:

```
tag_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words").text
```